# R enum-alike argument with match.arg: How to choose a non-first element as default value?

Tags: r, function, enums, arguments

How can I declare another than the first of multiple allowed argument values as default value (if no value was passed in)?

```
library(stats)

center <- function(x, type = c("mean", "median", "trimmed")) {
  type <- match.arg(type)
  switch(type,
         mean = mean(x),
         median = median(x),
         trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))
}

values <- c(100, 120, 200)

center(values, "median")
# [1] 120

center(values, "mean")
# [1] 140

# uses the first value "mean" as the default!
center(values)  
# [1] 140
```

I would like to see the default value in the function signature if possible in order to make the default value explicit (visible), e. g. (non-working pseudo-code!) to make the second element the default value:

```
center <- function(x, type = c("mean", "median", "trimmed")[2]) {...
```

Other proposals are also welcome!

PS: I could put the default value always in the first position but if there is a logical order in the list I would prefer to keep it (e. g. `payment.frequency = c("monthly", "quarterly", "semi-annually", "annually")`.

Comment: @RichScriven: I want to call center(values) but want to specify the 2nd value as default value in the function declaration (not the call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify `match.arg` to take the second `arg` value instead of the first. It's just a matter of finding and replacing that line in the function body.

```
matchArg <- base::match.arg
body(matchArg)[[c(4, 3, 2, 3)]] <- quote(return(arg[2L]))
```

Now we replace `match.arg` with our new `matchArg` function inside `center`, and we will now get the second `type` value (the median) by default.

```
center <- function(x, type = c("mean", "median", "trimmed")) {
  type <- matchArg(type)
  switch(type,
         mean = mean(x),
         median = median(x),
         trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))
}

values <- c(100, 120, 200)

center(values)  
# [1] 120
center(values, "mean")
# [1] 140
```

Of course, this doesn't meet your visibility requirement. But it's an idea.

Comment: Visibility is an optional wish, my top 1 favorite was also to modify `match.arg` and add an parameter to specify the default value which would make the default value visible within the function body at least. THX for showing such sophisticated way of programming (modifying the parse tree of the function body :-)

Comment: @ALL: To view the AST of the function body you can use `pryr::call_tree(body(matchArg))`

Comment: @rich-scriven. This is cool. As a minor coding point, you could use recursive indexing here in your second line, replacing `body(matchArg)[[4]][[3]][[2]][[3]]` with `body(matchArg)[[c(4, 3, 2, 3)]]`. It's a matter of taste, of course, but has fewer characters.

Comment: @lmo - Nice one!  Added to the post.  Thank you!  Really awesome that R allows that too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the accepted answer of @RichScriven who showed how to modify `match.arg` I have found **a way to also annotate the default value in the function signature (which was an optional wish in my question)**.

The trick is to "annotate" the default value using a name for the vector element:

```
matchArg <- base::match.arg
body(matchArg)[[c(4, 3, 2, 3)]] <- quote(
  return(
    if ("default" %in% names(arg)) {
      arg[["default"]] }
    else {
      arg[[1L]]
    })
)

center <- function(x, type = c("mean", default = "median", "trimmed")) {
  type <- matchArg(type)
  switch(type,
         mean = mean(x),
         median = median(x),
         trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))
}
```

Now the default value is the (annotated) second one:

```
> values <- c(100, 120, 200)
> center(values, "median")
[1] 120
> center(values, "mean")
[1] 140
> center(values)
[1] 120
```

PS: This solution would be worth a patch for base R if enough user think this feature is required...